# matplotlib pyplot.plot(): How do you plot data as a line when the data contains a single value surrounded by masks?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I'm plotting a series of data as a line. My data contains quite few gaps, and some times there is a single data point surrounded by masked values, as in the following example.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot

x = np.arange(0,6)
y = np.ma.array(x,mask = [0,0,1,1,0,1])
pyplot.figure()
ax = pyplot.subplot(111)
pyplot.plot(x, y, )
print x, y
pyplot.show()
```

If you were to plot this, you'd get a line from zero to 1., but nothing at 4. Can anyone think of a simple way to plot this data such that the point that is surrounded by masked values is visible?

I want to keep this as a line, instead of a scatter plot or histogram.

Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to adapt the line style by adding a marker.

```
pyplot.plot(x, y, 'o-')
```

To prevent the marker from ending up in the top-right corner of the plot, you could add:

```
ax.set_xlim(np.min(x),np.max(x))
ax.set_ylim(np.min(y.data),np.max(y.data))
```